# Question tag score and suggesting tag synonyms?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

On the [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/), in order to be able to propose a tag synonym you need:

> more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag

What about people with a high question score on a tag, shouldn't we be able to suggest them to? For the tag I was planning to suggest a synonym for, I currently have a total question score of 17, but I'm not allowed to suggest them as I've not got the answer score. Would it not make sense to say require an answer score of 5, or a question score of perhaps 10? (Or maybe even 5, but given that question score doesn't currently count perhaps the bar needs to be set higher)

Comment: The same is happening for me and I do have 5 answer score as well as 5 question score. Does the software only look at these scores at the end of every day or something?

Comment: For the purposes of linking questions, tag score is described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106927/1438