# What is the difference between score and reputation?

Tags: support

I have seen score in my user tag section. I don't understand the difference between score and reputation.

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The score is simply the number of upvotes minus the number of down-vote; so, if you have an answer with 3 up-votes and 1 down-vote, then you will have a score of 2 on that answer.

For each up-vote you (usually) get 10 reputation, and -2 reputation for each down-vote; so, for the answer above, you'd get effectively 28 reputation.

Note that reputation from votes is limited to 200 per day, and there are other sources of reputation as well.

Comment: Also upvotes to questions affect rep but not the score. Answers on CW questions don't count towards either. So its the number of upvotes on non-cw answers. Of course that info is on the tool-tip